# Determining if layer is WMS/WFS with PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, wms, wfs

In QGIS with a python plugin, how can I determine if a layer is WMS, WFS or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [QgsVectorLayer::providerType()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ae24b39559eb1584b69966bcc475bf23a) method to determine the data provider of the layer in question:

```
vLayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, "WFS_layer", "WFS")
vLayer.providerType()
>>> u'WFS'

rLayer = QgsRasterLayer(url, 'WMS_layer', 'wms')
rLayer.providerType()
>>> u'wms'
```

Comment: Any idea why **WFS** is upercase compared to **wms**? Or could **wfs** also exist?

Comment: @pathmapper - That's a good question, one I would suggest you [ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) as I am unsure.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, done in https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/348620/105333