# Are there other values than "wms" and "WFS" for providerType() for a WMS/WFS layer?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

According to the [docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a21d77a908e4bdebeae25e8599812997f), `providerType()` returns the provider type (provider key) for a layer.

According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/262050/105333, the values for a WMS/WFS layer are `wms` and `WFS`.

I found no documentation why `wms` is in lowercase and `WFS` is in uppercase. Also there seems to be no list of all existing provider types available.

This raises the question, if there are additionally other values like e.g. `WMS` or `wfs` around.

Comment: Certainly doesn't follow OGC service type parameter values, which are uppercase WMS, WMTS, WFS, WCS, SOS, WPS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!,you can find the provider in the "**about**" dialog.

[image]

or if you want use python, you can obtain the initial providers list. @germán-carrillo suggestion

```
QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
```

which returns for the above list from the "**about**" diolog the following values:

```
['DB2', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'grass', 'grassraster', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'ows', 'postgres', 'spatialite', 'virtual', 'wcs', 'wms']
```

About your question of why it's in uppercase or lowercase, I think it's simply because it's so defined in the code

"**wms**" https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/wms/qgswmsprovider.cpp#L77

"**WFS**"
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/providers/wfs/qgswfsprovider.cpp#L52

Comment: QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()